# Formulating a query to detect inconsistent data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
 a_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
);

CREATE TABLE b {
 b_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
};

CREATE TABLE cross (
 a_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 b_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (a_id),
 KEY (b_id),
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a (a_id),
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b (b_id)
);

CREATE TABLE prices (
 a_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 price int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (a_id),
 CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a (a_id)
);
```

I would like to retrieve every b_id value for which there are inconsistent prices. A b.id value 'B' has an inconsistent price if the following conditions both hold:

1. There exist two a_id values (say, 'A1' and 'A2') such that table `cross` contains both ('A1', 'B') and ('A2', 'B'). (For any b_id value, there may be zero or more rows in `cross`.)
2. Either 'A1' and 'A2' correspond to rows of `prices` that have different values of `price`, or else exactly one of 'A1' and 'A2' corresponds to an entry in `prices`.

Because of restrictions by the hosting provider, I cannot use stored procedures with this data base. I haven't figured out a sensible way to do this with SQL queries. So far, I've resorted to retrieving all relevant data and scanning for inconsistencies in Perl. That's a lot of data retrieval. Is there a better way? (I'm using InnoDB, if it makes a difference.)

Comment: Ted, I'm not understanding the rules to identify the rows you are looking for.

Comment: I'm stuck on the second part of condition #2: "or else exactly one of 'A1' and 'A2' corresponds to an entry in prices."  Are you saying that if there's two 'A' records, but only one has a price... then it's inconsistent... but if none of the 'A' records have a price, then it's OK?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson - That's correct. If no 'A' records have a price, that's okay. If there exist two (or more) 'A' records for a given 'B', then if any of them has a price, they all must have a price and it must be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* Condition 1 and Condition 2a */ 
SELECT 
    c.b_id
FROM
    `cross` AS c
    JOIN prices AS p ON (p.a_id = c.a_id)
GROUP BY
    c.b_id
HAVING
    COUNT(c.a_id) > 1 AND
    MAX(p.price) != MIN(p.price)

UNION

/* Condition 1 and Condition 2b */
SELECT 
    c.b_id
FROM
    `cross` AS c
    LEFT JOIN prices AS p ON (p.a_id = c.a_id)
GROUP BY
    c.b_id
HAVING
    COUNT(c.a_id) > 1 AND
    SUM(IF(p.price IS NULL, 0 ,1)) = 1;
```